# IBM DB2 SQL Count always return 1 with multiple rows

Tags: sql, db2

This query return all the proper field in a web grid. Users wants to know total of rows.
I add a COUNT and a GROUP BY. The count always return the value 1. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT A.SOPSEQ, A.SOPNBR, B.REVUSR2 , COUNT(A.SOPSEQ) AS AAA
      FROM @SOP A
      INNER JOIN @SOPREV B on B.SOPSEQ = A.SOPSEQ
      WHERE UPPER(A.SOPSTS) = 'IN REVIEW' AND UPPER(B.REVSTS) = 'IN REVIEW'
      GROUP BY A.SOPSEQ, A.SOPNBR, B.REVUSR2
      ORDER BY A.SOPNBR, A.SOPREV

      OFFSET (:StartingRow - 1) * :NbrOfRows ROWS
      FETCH NEXT :NbrOfRows + 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Where is the other query and some data?

Comment: It's the exact same query without the COUNT and GROUP BY. Both Query returns the proper values in each columns. That part works. The COUNT always Return the value 1.

Comment: I removed some fields to make it easier to read.

Comment: Really need example data and what you results you want vs what you are getting...

Comment: As an additional row of the result set

Comment: I added  OVER() and now I am getting a row count.  COUNT(A.SOPSEQ) OVER () AS AAA   However I want a row count of SOP and not SOPREV

Comment: I am thinking maybe what I am looking for is union all ??